# Converting string to bytes32 to be used in solidity contract call

Tags: string, perl

How can I convert a Perl string to bytes32 like the java function below:

```
public static Bytes32 stringToBytes32(String string) {
    byte[] byteValue = string.getBytes();
    byte[] byteValueLen32 = new byte[32];
    System.arraycopy(byteValue, 0, byteValueLen32, 0, byteValue.length);
    return new Bytes32(byteValueLen32);
}
```

Is there any module available in CPAN to do this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all this function does it to encode a string into bytes, then truncate/pad it so the result is exactly 32 bytes long.

The first part may be tricky because [according to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()):

> ```
> public byte[] getBytes()
> ```
>
> Encodes this `String` into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.
>
> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the default charset is unspecified.

Perl doesn't really have a concept of a "default charset", but if you're willing to settle for UTF-8, it's not hard:

```
sub stringToBytes32 {
    my ($str) = @_;
    utf8::encode $str;
    return pack 'a32', $str;
}
```

(See [`Encode::encode`](https://perldoc.pl/Encode#encode) if you need a different encoding.)

[`pack`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/pack) is handy for producing data in binary formats. Here we use it to truncate/pad to 32 bytes.